# Nos títulos dos certificados, coloca-se maiúsculas ou minúsculas?

Tags: maiúsculas-e-minúsculas

Devemos escrever "Bacharel em Meios de Comunicação Social", certo? Ou seja, me refiro a escrever o bacharel, licenciado etc e o campo dele com iniciais maiúsculas.

É que mandei meu currículo em português para uma tradutora brasileira, e ela deixou a parte de "Bacharel em Meios de Comunicação Social" sem correções, enquanto corrigiu o título do outro certificado ("Certificado Profissional em Ensinar Árabe como Língua Estrangeira" para "Certificado profissional em ensino de árabe como língua estrangeira"). Eu não sei se a correção dela é correta quanto às minúsculas. Quero ter certeza, por favor, porque estou confusa.

Comment: Procurei e não achei uma regra específica para isso. Mas como é um Título, acredito que tenha que seguir a regra de Título (de uma redação por exemplo). Deixaria conforme o Título de Bacharel.

Comment: Obrigada. Aprecio muito sua ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisei bastante e não achei nenhuma regra específica para Títulos de Bacharel, cursos e etc. Porém achei a regra geral de Títulos que foi modificada com o Acordo Ortográfico 2009. São 3 regras que seguem abaixo. No caso do teu currículo, seria ótimo se seguisse um padrão, ou seja, uma das três regras. Eu particularmente, prefiro escrever cada palavra com a primeira letra maiuscúla, mas deixando claro que qualquer forma estará correto.

> Existem três maneiras de redigir um título.
>
> O Acordo Ortográfico 2009 permite usar maiúsculas ou minúsculas nos
>   bibliônimos, isto é, nos nomes ou títulos de livros e obras impressas.
>   Eis sua redação: Base XIX. “1º) A letra minúscula inicial é usada:
>   (...) c) Nos bibliónimos/bibliônimos (após o primeiro elemento, que é
>   com maiúscula, os demais vocábulos podem ser escritos com minúscula,
>   salvo nos nomes próprios nele contidos, tudo em grifo): O Senhor do
>   Paço de Ninães ou O senhor do paço de Ninães, Menino de engenho ou
>   Menino de Engenho, Árvore e Tambor ou Árvore e tambor.”
>
> O Acordo, entretanto, não menciona nada sobre as partículas (embora
>   nos três exemplos elas estejam em minúscula) caso se prefira escrever
>   o título com as iniciais maiúsculas.  Reza a lei ortográfica de 1943
>   que a inicial de cada palavra do título, à exceção das partículas
>   monossilábicas, deve ser grafada com letra maiúscula. Partícula, em
>   gramática, é “palavra invariável que tem função gramatical, mas que
>   não é facilmente classificada numa das partes do discurso” (dic.
>   Aurélio). Nesse caso, escreve-se: Memórias de um Sargento de Milícias.
>   E também, por exemplo:
>
> Oração aos Moços
>
> Poesia Completa de Cruz e Sousa
>
> O Evangelho Segundo São João
>
> O problema é que há palavras invariáveis e combinações de partículas
>   de mais de uma sílaba, como “contra, para, sobre, desde, acerca,
>   pelo”. E até de mais sílabas: “durante, consoante, segundo, conforme”.
>   E se as últimas três podem ser escritas em minúsculas, por que “de
>   acordo com” não poderia? E ainda há o caso dos artigos: monossilábicos
>   mas não invariáveis, são todavia considerados partículas. Desse modo,
>   o livro de D. H. Lawrence “A Virgem e o Cigano” ficaria “A Virgem e O
>   Cigano”, mas assim nunca se escreveu.
>
> É evidente que há uma dificuldade prática no reconhecimento das
>   partículas. Então, qual a solução quando não se sabe reconhecer o que
>   é partícula, ou mesmo quando há muitas delas no título? A melhor opção
>   é a segunda oferecida pelo Acordo Ortográfico 2009: escrever apenas a
>   primeira letra inicial com maiúscula e as demais em minúsculas, a não
>   ser que haja no título um nome próprio, o qual neste caso conserva sua
>   inicial maiúscula. Exemplos:
>
> Memórias de um sargento de milícias
>
> Poesia completa de Cruz e Sousa
>
> Como fazer uma pizza em dez minutos
>
> Anotações e revelações sobre o novo Código Civil
>
> Constituição do Estado de Santa Catarina
>
> Discussões em torno dos direitos fundamentais no Brasil
>
> A última opção seria escrever todo o título com maiúsculas ou
>   caixa-alta:
>
> MEMÓRIAS DE UM SARGENTO DE MILÍCIAS
>
> A VIRGEM E O CIGANO
>
> O EVANGELHO SEGUNDO SÃO JOÃO
>
> Uma observação: tanto os títulos de livros e artigos quanto os de
>   ensaios e dissertações (acadêmicas, de vestibular, de concurso, etc.)
>   não devem apresentar o ponto final. Este até pode ser usado, mas
>   apenas quando o título contém um verbo, ou seja, quando configura uma
>   oração. Tome-se como exemplo dessa exceção o título de uma redação de
>   vestibular:
>
> O homem contemporâneo não sabe lidar com a antiguidade.
>
> O HOMEM CONTEMPORÂNEO NÃO SABE LIDAR COM A ANTIGUIDADE.

[Fonte](http://www.linguabrasil.com.br/nao-tropece-detail.php?id=417)

Comment: Aprecio muito sua ajuda e seu esforço. Saudações. :)

Comment: Mas então, a gente não pode escrever "como" com a inicial maiúscula? (Porque tem 2 sílabas)
E desculpe por perguntar tão tarde.

Comment: As particulas devem ter a primeira letra minusculas. O *como* é uma particula, nesse caso. Ou se escreve tudo em maisculo (que eu acho não muito elegante para um currículo).

Comment: Obrigada pela sua resposta. Aprecio muito.